# Facebook "Unauthorized IP address" exception

Tags: facebook, unauthorized

My facebook app doesn't work in production environment.

On localhost everything works fine, but in production environment Facebook returns "unauthorized IP address" exception.

I use https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk lib

My request:

```
   $facebook = new App_Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $this->fbAppId,
        'secret' => $this->fbAppSecret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    $session = $facebook->getSession();


    if (empty($session) || empty($user)) {
        throw new Exception('Error facebook connect');
    }

    try {
        $fbFriends = $facebook->api('/me/friends',array('fields'=>array('name','id')));
    } catch (App_Facebook_ApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
```

Does anybody know what is it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.facebook.com/developers/ 
Click on your app in the "my apps" section on the right 
Click "Edit settings" 
Click on the "Advanced" section on the left 
Check the "security" section. I think you need to modify some the ip whitelist settings

Comment: No, Server Whitelist in app settings is blank

Comment: @Sergey, sounds like Jeroen hit the problem on the nail if your whitelist is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure. If the whitelist is empty, I assume it doesn't use a whitelist at all, and will accept any IP. Not exactly 100% sure, since it has been a while since I did FB development.

Comment: I'm sure that problem is not in the white list. I tried to add server IP to the whitelist, but it did not give any result. At the same time everything worked fine in development environment with empty whitelist. Its make me crazy.

Comment: I am going through the same issue. @Sergey how did u fix it